# How to obtain the average of a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset such as below:

```
data = { "size":["2","5mm","10mm","12-15mm","16-19mm"] }
dt =pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I need to obtain the average of each cell and replace it with the range (in float)?

So, the out put is

```
[2,5,10,13.5,17.5]
```

What i did is:

```
begin = dt["size"].str.replace("mm", "").split("-")[0]
```

it complains with an error,

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Also, i am not sure if it is the best practice.

***What is best approach to obtain the average of this string ranges?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
print(dt['size'].str.rstrip('mm').str.split('-', expand=True).astype(float).mean(1))
```

Or use:

```
print(dt['size'].str.rstrip('mm').apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split('-'))) / len(x.split('-'))).astype(float))
```

Output:

```
0     2.0
1     5.0
2    10.0
3    13.5
4    17.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: when i run it in my real code, it complains with `dt['Size'].str.rstrip('mm').apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split('-'))) / len(x.split('-'))).astype(float)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'` Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Using `str.findall` with `.apply`

**Ex:**

```
data = { "size":["2","5mm","10mm","12-15mm","16-19mm"] }
dt =pd.DataFrame(data=data)

dt["size_m"] = dt["size"].str.findall("(\d+)").apply(lambda x: sum(map(float, x))/len(x))
print(dt)
```

**Output:**

```
      size  size_m
0        2     2.0
1      5mm     5.0
2     10mm    10.0
3  12-15mm    13.5
4  16-19mm    17.5
```

Comment: Although, it works well for provided sample in the question, when i run it in my real code it complains with:
`dt['Size)'].str.findall("(\d+)").apply(lambda x: sum(map(float, x))/len(x))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure here, as I do not use python on a daily basis. But I suppose the issue maybe the return of the `str.replace("mm","")` - which seems to returns `JSON` instead of an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

One other, non-pandas, option is to use `mean()` from `statistics` module.

```
import statistics

data = {"size": ["2", "5mm", "10mm", "12-15mm", "16-19mm"]}

size_ranges = (size.replace("mm", "").split("-") for size in data["size"])
averages = [statistics.mean([int(s) for s in size_range]) for size_range in size_ranges]
print(averages)
# [2, 5, 10, 13.5, 17.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
data = { "size":["2","5mm","10mm","12-15mm","16-19mm"] }
dt =pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(dt['size'].str.rstrip('mm').apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, x.split('-'))) / len(x.split('-'))).astype(float).tolist())

Answer (score 0):

I am not specialist, but I will do it this way:

```py
import numpy as np

data = { "size":["2","5mm","10mm","12-15mm","16-19mm"] }

def rangeToAvr(strData):
    """transform 'strData' to float"""
    strData = strData.replace('m', '-')
    strData = strData.split('-')
    strData = list(filter(None, strData))

    strData = [float(d) for d in strData]
    res = np.mean(strData)

    return res


def transform_data(data):
    """transfrom data to wanted form"""
    sizeData = data['size']

    data['size'] = list(map(rangeToAvr, sizeData))

    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = transform_data(data)

    print(data)


>>>{'size': [2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 13.5, 17.5]}
```